# Introducing Stack Exchange Research Support and Fellowship Program

Tags: discussion

The mission of Stack Exchange is to make the internet a better place to get expert answers to your questions. The Stack Exchange Fellowship Program aims to support students conducting research in subjects related to our academic Q&A sites in order to (a) increase the quality of information in a particular subject and (b) facilitate the exchange of information between experts in the field. Individual awards range from 250 to 1000 dollars (USD).

Applicants should be advanced undergraduate, graduate students or professionals pursuing research related to one the following Stack Exchange sites:

- [English](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2077/13231)
- [Linguistics](https://linguistics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/202/344)
- [Physics](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/942/5450)
- [Statistics](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/942/5450)
- Theoretical Computer Science
- [Theoretical Physics](http://meta.theoreticalphysics.stackexchange.com/q/170/533)

Applications will be accepted on a rolling basis starting immediately. For more details and to apply, check out the [application](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/37818223/SE%20Fellowship%20Application.docx)!

We are also accepting volunteers from the community to help review applications. Volunteers should have some level of expertise in the subject area (professors and those who have or are pursuing advanced degrees are ideal candidates). Reviewers will be given 3 weeks from when they receive materials or may request more time if needed. Following the first wave of submissions, those selected to be Stack Exchange Fellows will be asked to review 3 to 4 new applications. To facilitate the review process, reviewers will rate applications on several scales instead of making judgments on funding. You can find the Reviewer Form [here](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/37818223/Reviewer%20Sheet.docx).

Reviewers and successful candidates are encouraged to customize the "about me" section of the user profile by including information on:

1. Area of expertise and current occupation
2. Key academic goals/milestones
3. Role in the Fellowship program (applicant, reviewer, fellow, both)
4. SE grant project, if applicable

If you have any questions regarding the Fellowship Program, or would like more information about applying or becoming a reviewer, please email *academics@stackexchange.com*.

Edited: Applications accepted on a rolling basis until December 31, 2011.

Comment: This seems like a great idea. I was wondering if you could provide more details about the scope of the program, expected time frame for projects, and what the reviewing timeline would look like ?

Comment: @SureshVenkat Thanks. Great questions. Post is updated with reviewer time frame. Project scope and time frame is flexible and is addressed in the application.

Comment: thanks ! btw the document that you've linked to doesn't have a mention of Theoretical Computer Science.

Comment: Fixed. Thanks @SureshVenkat.

Comment: _great idea_ is this program still active? is there any further info about its outcome/history?

Answer (score 5):

Will the results of the research be published or covered by an NDA?  This would affect my willingness to be a reviewer.

Comment: Individuals may choose to share there research with the community or write it up in an SE blog post or not at all. The results of research will not be covered under an NDA.

Answer (score 4):

Is there a deadline for submissions ? I don't think I saw one.

Comment: Updated- Accepted on a rolling basis until December 31.

Answer (score 3):

I just finished my undergraduate studies and I hope to be a graduate student the next year. Will a similar program be available for 2012, or for that matter, in years to come?

Comment: Future rounds of the Fellowship will depend on the success of this first round. We will announce it as soon as we know.